# Error when create instance generic type with autoMock

Tags: .net, generics, moq, autofac

Im using `Autofac.extras.moq` ,when i create new instance with function with Generic

```
    IReadOnlyRepository<T> _campaignRepository;
    IReadOnlyRepository<DMA> _dmaRepository;
    public DigitalCampaignService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
    {
        using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
        {

            mock.Provide(mock.Create<IReadOnlyRepository<T>>());
            _dmaRepository = mock.Provide<IReadOnlyRepository<DMA>>(new GenericReadOnlyRepository<DMA>(Constants.CONNECTION_STRING));
        }


    }
```

function **IReadOnlyRepository** need to be instance

```
namespace Kolabs.Infrastructure
{
    public interface IReadOnlyRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, int? numberOfItems = default(int?));
        IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string orderBy, int? numberOfItems = default(int?));
        IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, [Dynamic(new[] { false, false, false, true })] Expression<Func<T, dynamic>> orderBy, OrderDirection orderDirection = OrderDirection.Ascending, int? numberOfItems = default(int?));
        IEnumerable<T> FindAll(int? numberOfItems = default(int?));
        IEnumerable<T> FindAll(string orderBy, int? numberOfItems = default(int?));
        T FindById(int id);
        T FindOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    }
}
```

I'm get the error message when run code

> An exception of type 'Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The requested service 'Kolabs.Infrastructure.IReadOnlyRepository`1[[Maestro.Model.Campaigns.FacebookCampaign, Maestro.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Comment: Check your *app.config* file and see if there is a `bindingRedirect` pointing to the wrong version.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error after updating packages. Reverted back to older versions did the trick.

Not working:

- Autofac 4.6.2
- Autofac.Extras.Moq 4.2.0
- Castle.Core 4.2.1

Working:

- Autofac 4.6.0
- Autofac.Extras.Moq 4.0.0
- Castle.Core 4.1.1

Comment: Check your *app.config* file and see if there is a `bindingRedirect` pointing to the wrong version.

Comment: downgrade to Autofac.Extras.Moq 4.0.0 is enough